# Feed from multiple models (sorted by the time they were added to the feed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a simple Rails bookmarking app that lets users save Items and organize them in Collections.

I'd like to add an index page with staff picks that includes both selected Items and Collections. The result would be a feed that ranks these Items and Collections by the time they were selected as staff picks (not by the time they were initially created).

Here's what I have so far:

**Feed Model**

```
class Feed < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feed_entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :feed_entries
  has_many :collections, through: :feed_entries
end
```

**Feed Entry Model**

```
class FeedEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :feed 
end
```

**Item Model**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feed_entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feeds, through: :feed_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :feeds
end
```

**Collection Model**

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feed_entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feeds, through: :feed_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :feeds
end
```

**Feeds Controller**

```
class FeedsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @feed = Feed.find_by(feed_name: 'staffpicks')
        @feed_items = @feed.items.includes(:feed_entries).order('feed_entries.created_at DESC')
        @feed_collections = @feed.collections.includes(:feed_entries).order('feed_entries.created_at DESC')
   end
end
```

So at this point I'm able to list staff-picked Items and Collections sorted by the time they were selected. But I can't figure out how to combine the two.

```
@everything = (@feed_collections + @feed_items)
```

I tried this, but I can't use *order* on an array and when I append *.sort_by(&:created_at)* it sorts by the creation date of the respective Item and Collection - not by when they were added to the array.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Many thanks in advance. I'm new to programming and Rails, so your feedback is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Feed < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feed_entries, dependent: :destroy,
     -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  has_many :items, through: :feed_entries
  has_many :collections, through: :feed_entries
end

class FeedEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, optional: true
  belongs_to :collection, optional: true
  belongs_to :feed 

  def entry
    item || collection
  end
end

@feed = Feed.eager_load(feed_entries: [:item, :collection]).find(1)
@entrees = @feed.feed_entries.map(&:entry)
```

You should also consider setting this up as a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) instead of using two different foreign keys as that will let you treat both items and collections as single homogenous association.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it! :)

(FYI I upvoted your answer, but don't seem to have enough rep yet)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the feed_entries association.

@feeds = feed_entries.includes(:item, :collection).order(“feed_entries.created_at desc”)